# Has any MOOC (Coursera, edX, Udacity or others) publicly released some of their student data?

Tags: data-request, education

I'm looking for educational datasets from MOOCs. [PSLC DataShop](https://pslcdatashop.web.cmu.edu/) contains some learning interaction data, but not from MOOCs. I'm especially interested in logs tracking students' activities such as browsing the website or submitting answers.

Comment: Were you able to find any sources within the students' activities? I'm looking for similar data to no avail.

Comment: @kyleED I haven't found any interesting public sources for the students' activities.

Answer (score 7):

From my knowledge, Coursera uses Backbone.js for their site, so you can find several JSON endpoints with a lot of data. Unfortunately, I am not familiar with Backbone and the only links I know are from Google

List of all courses - https://www.coursera.org/maestro/api/topic/list?full=1

Another list of courses - https://www.coursera.org/maestro/api/topic/list2

List of all universities - https://www.coursera.org/maestro/api/university/list

Information about a specific course - https://www.coursera.org/maestro/api/topic/information?topic-id=compdata

Maybe if you are familiar with those technologies, you can find other links with more details and maybe with non-personal data you may find interesting.

**UPDATE**
Also, this user seems to have a lot of data about MOOC (completion rates etc). Maybe you can contact with him and ask him to share them with you.

http://moocmoocher.wordpress.com/2013/02/13/synthesising-mooc-completion-rates/

Answer (score 7):

Udacity just (August 12, 2014) released an API that makes all of their course information easily available:

See the overview here: [Udacity Course Catalog API](https://www.udacity.com/catalog-api)

And the documentation here: [Udacity Course Catalog API Documentation](https://s3.amazonaws.com/content.udacity-data.com/techdocs/UdacityCourseCatalogAPIDocumentation-v0.pdf)

Some other APIs that have online course data:

- Coursera has an entire "[App Platform](https://tech.coursera.org/app-platform/)" including Catalog API
- Udemy has an [API](https://developers.udemy.com/) (version 1.1)
- EdX has an RSS feed of their courses (and a [full API on their roadmap](http://apievangelist.com/2014/06/09/the-edx-api/))

Comment: Nice APIs, thanks! Actually I had mostly in mind *student* data, but that's very good to know too.

Answer (score 4):

The staff from the [metadata](https://www.coursera.org/course/metadata) course on coursera posted some statistics, which I aggregated [here](http://pastebin.com/DSb1uGAu).

Answer (score 4):

How about this?

[MIT and Harvard release de-identified learning data from open online courses](https://newsoffice.mit.edu/2014/mit-and-harvard-release-de-identified-learning-data-open-online-courses)

[Data](http://thedata.harvard.edu/dvn/dv/mxhx/):

[image]

Comment: Thanks, that's nice but there is barely any information for each student :( (see screenshot that I added in your answer). A few MB compared to ~ 10 GB by course when they receive the database dump from edX.

Answer (score 1):

I come after the storm but:

- Yu, J., Luo, G., Xiao, T., Zhong, Q., Wang, Y., Feng, W., ... & Tang, J. (2020, July). **MOOCCube: a large-scale data repository for NLP applications in MOOCs.** In Proceedings of the 58th annual meeting of the association for computational linguistics (pp. 3135-3142). http://moocdata.cn/data/MOOCCube
- Kuzilek J., Hlosta M., Zdrahal Z. **Open University Learning Analytics dataset** Sci. Data 4:170171 doi: 10.1038/sdata.2017.171 (2017). https://analyse.kmi.open.ac.uk/open_dataset (preview on [Kaggle](https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/rocki37/open-university-learning-analytics-dataset))
- Choi, Y., Lee, Y., Shin, D., Cho, J., Park, S., Lee, S., Baek, J., Kim, B., & Jang, Y. (2019). **EdNet: A Large-Scale Hierarchical Dataset in Education.** Artificial Intelligence in Education, 12164, 69-73. https://github.com/riiid/ednet
- (only exercises) P. J. Chen, M. E. Hsieh, T. Y. Tsai. **Junyi Online Learning Dataset: A large-scale public online learning activity dataset from elementary to senior high school students.**, 2020. Available from https://www.kaggle.com/junyiacademy/learning-activity-public-dataset-by-junyi-academy.

I am notably interested if content is available; it seems that Junyi contains problem titles in Taiwanese, and MOOCCube contains a lot of content information.